Driver Scripted expression showing the wrong value
So I have a basic driver that is supposed to divide 360º between the number of copies on an array modifier (count). This way the empty in the middle, which is being used in the array modifier of the head as the source, is supposed to rotate the number of degrees necessary to evenly spread out the copies on a circle.
However the number that appears in the rotation is completely different to the one I expect, even though the 'Driver Value' says that the value is what it is supposed to be (360/12=30 in this case)

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?
I know rotations get a bit weird with radians and degrees when you do stuff like geometry nodes but this doesn't seem to involve that at all.

as you already mentioned, Blender uses radians internally. So just replace your 360 degrees with tau, and it works.

Thanks, that did solve it. I still find it pretty weird that the rotation displays the number in degrees but it's somehow using a completely different system underneath...

yes, it is a bit confusing in the beginning ;)
